# Grep command stopped working

Tags: unix

Suddenly grep command stopped working. When I did the ls -l ~/grep showing the one file in my home directory.But this file has been present for ages. If I give command which grep  --> pointing to /bin/grep and with /bin/grep it is working fine. Can anyone please suggest.

Thanks,

Regards,
Shiv

Comment: The file grep present in my home directory is a zero byte file.

Comment: Check your `PATH` environmental variable:  `echo $PATH`.  This should list all, and only, directories in which you want executable files to be found.  Your home directory usually shouldn't be in the list.

Comment: Hi Mars, It is returning  .:/bin:/usr/bin:/  ...etc with long list. Could you please suggest which directory Do I need to search. Bu this file grep mentioned above is present in my home directory also. Could you please advice. Thanks

Comment: Yes Mars the echo $PATH did not return my home directory which contain zero byte file named grep present from ages. But why now grep command is not working. Could you please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete the zero-byte file in your home directory.  It's not doing anything.  (I don't know how it got there.)  The problem is that the first entry in `PATH`, ".", points to whatever directory you're in.  So when you're in your home directory, the shell (bash, I assume) looks for `grep` in the current directory, and finds the file that's there, which can't do anything.

I consider it a bad idea to have "." in your path. It's convenient, and natural if you're coming from the Windows world, but it means that what gets executed can change depending on what directory you're in (as you have now seen).  It also means that if you're on a multiuser system, someone can put an executable in one of their directories, and then when you `cd` into their directory, all of a sudden you're executing their code, which might not be what you want, and could be dangerous.

Instead, remove ".:" (dot colon) from your `PATH`.  When you need to run a script in the current directory, add "./" to its name to execute it.  "/bin" and "/usr/bin" should usually be at the front of the list.  Some people prefer to put "/usr/local/bin" at the front of the list, or something else.

You can change your `PATH` by editing .profile or .bash_profile or .bashrc.  It depends on how you have your shell set up.  Be careful to separate each directory path in `PATH` with one ":" character.

Comment: Hi Mars, You mean some one changed the .profile or .bash_profile or .bashrc  path value in that file. If yes, how can we know who changed this. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Maybe the zero-byte file is new.  Maybe you've never tried to run grep from your home directory before now.  You can easily check ownership and last access times of files (if they still exist).  Finding what account did something is more difficult--maybe impossible.  If you really think that's what happened and want to know who did it, you'll need to do some deeper research on that topic, maybe specific two your particular OS.  It's probably very non-trivial, although I could be wrong.  I have no idea.